# How to place a variable inside getElementbyId() that changes during each repetition of a loop?

Tags: javascript

I want something similar to f" {variable} " of python

Ive tried

```
function press()
{
  for(var i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    if(!document.getElementById('ip'+i).value)
    {
      alert("error");
      break;
    }
  }
```

but it didnt work.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] and explain what _"didn't work"_ means -> _""It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: [Should work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/yk9humq6/).

Comment: What isn't working? You are breaking on the first condition that fails which exits the loop.

Comment: There is something similar in modern JavaScript. It's called [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). But the root of your problem is in something completely different.

Comment: If `getElementById` can return `null` in your scenario, accessing `value` can result in a Type Error. check the returned value first, or use optional chaining operator `?.`

Comment: Before editing your question, you mentioned that you get error alert only for the first field but not for the rest. Can it be related to the fact that your browser is blocking similar alert windows? Try to replace `alert("error")` with `console.log("error")` and check in the console.

Comment: if this is about checking required input fields, maybe consider using the browser's native handling of `required` `<input>`s inside a `<form>` element

Comment: @DustInCompetent yes this was the issue, thank you very much

Comment: @VisioN thanks for the help, the issue was the null value in the first repetition as DustinCompetent said

Answer (score -2):

> I want something similar to f" {variable} " of python

#### template strings `${variable}`

In JavaScript you can use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)
The usage is
` `${variable}` `

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', press)

function press() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (!document.getElementById(`ip${i}`).value) {
      alert("error");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="ip0"/>
<input id="ip1"/>
<input id="ip2"/>
<input id="ip3"/>

<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: Maybe... OPs thinks that `'ip' + i` _"doesn't work"_ although it clearly does. Adding a "use template literals" won't change anything because OPs script works as is.

Comment: OP asked How to place a variable inside getElementById and also for something simliar like formatted strings in python and this answers this indeed ...

Comment: _"Ive tried ... but it didnt work."_ - But it works. See also the comments: _"hanks for the help, the issue was the null value in the first repetition"_

Comment: *I want something similar to f" {variable} " of python* OP clearly asked for this.